# Cant run my .exe file after converting it from .py

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I am a complete beginner to Python programming. I worked through a tutorial to develop an application. I used pyinstaller to convert it to a .exe file but now when I try to run the exe file I get the following error.

**"The ordinal 380 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Path\to\my\project"**

It runs fine until I convert it to an exe so I don't understand what is wrong. Here is the command that I run

**pyinstaller -F -w  file_name.py**

And here is the result that I get.

C:\Python\Bookmark Application>pyinstaller -F -w Bookmark.py
152 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.8
153 INFO: Python: 3.10.2
174 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
175 INFO: wrote C:\Python\Bookmark Application\Bookmark.spec
181 INFO: UPX is not available.
190 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Python\Bookmark Application']
498 INFO: checking Analysis
499 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
499 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
502 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
527 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5495 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
5496 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib'
7774 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7923 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7925 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
required by C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
7992 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python\Bookmark Application\Bookmark.py
8003 INFO: Processing module hooks...
8004 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8006 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8007 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8008 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8124 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8126 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8168 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8170 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8172 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8173 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8174 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8247 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
8418 INFO: checking Tree
8418 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
8418 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
8495 INFO: checking Tree
8495 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
8496 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
8598 INFO: checking Tree
8598 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
8599 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
8620 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
8635 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
8638 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
8645 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
8652 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
8661 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
8669 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
8679 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8997 INFO: Looking for eggs
8997 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll
8998 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
9000 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Python\Bookmark Application\build\Bookmark\warn-Bookmark.txt
9045 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Python\Bookmark Application\build\Bookmark\xref-Bookmark.html
9093 INFO: checking PYZ
9093 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
9094 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Python\Bookmark Application\build\Bookmark\PYZ-00.pyz
9463 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Python\Bookmark Application\build\Bookmark\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
9482 INFO: checking PKG
9482 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
9483 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Bookmark.pkg
16279 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Bookmark.pkg completed successfully.
16302 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
16302 INFO: checking EXE
16303 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
16303 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
16303 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Python\Bookmark Application\dist\Bookmark.exe
16311 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
16311 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\Users\10341735\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\images\icon-windowed.ico']
16320 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
16320 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
16320 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
16321 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
16321 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 38188 bytes
16321 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
16321 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
16321 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
16324 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
16324 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE
16325 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Python\Bookmark Application\dist\Bookmark.exe
16381 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
16384 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
18893 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Hi @KieranF, may I ask if you have  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable program installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded it

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is: How do I convert python to a single exe file?
You are on the correct path using pyinstaller but you need to specify that you want to compile it to 1 single file with the argument `--onefile`

The command should look like this:
`pyinstaller --onefile file_name.py`

Check out the Pyinstaller Manual: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Okay so I have done that now but now when I open the exe all I get is an empty command prompt screen and my code doesnt appear to run

Answer (score 2):

you are using the command wrong.

the command for pyinstaller - `pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py`

more documentation - [https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/]
[1](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

examples - https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: After making that change to the command when I try to run my program now all I get is a blank command prompt screen

Answer (score 1):

Besides the command usage error as pointed by the others , I'd recommend trying using [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) as an alternative to pyinstaller, [there is a great article on it](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-convert-a-python-script-to-an-executable-file-exe-4966e253c7e9) that contains all the basic steps and the documentation is self explanatory and the GUI is easy to use.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. i still get the blank python screen and it just stays there doing nothing.